# No man page for rails command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, manpage

I can't access rails man page. How can I fix this? Thanks

```
nuno@Houdini:~/workspace/depot_a$ man rails
man: can't resolve /usr/share/man/man1/rails.1.gz: No such file or directory
No manual entry for rails
```

edit: But how come some people have a man page and others don't?

Comment: Sorry can't help you on the problem, but there really is nothing helpful in the man page for rails. "rails --help" gives better info on the command and its uses.

Comment: Use `rails [sub_command] -h` to get help, and you need to execute it under the root of a ror project, except `rails new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails isn't a traditional operating system package, and usually isn't installed through apt-get or yum, but through the rubygems packaging system that does not install manpages for documentation.

Comment: Guess my mac is weird then since I do have a man rails... 
That it doesn't contain anything useful is a whole other matter..

Comment: @Rasmus In the case of OSX, a version of Rails ships with the operating system, so Apple chose to give it a man page for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Rails is a ruby gem. Those don't have man pages. Type `rails` to get a brief list of commands.

Answer (score 0):

For general help use either one of these:

```
rails -h
rails
```

For help on a specific command:

```
rails <cmd> -h
```

For example: `rails new -h`